# Como desabilitar libs da sugestão de imports do VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Meu time desenvolve em React com Typescript e estamos mudando a biblioteca de estilo para uma mais moderna. O problema é que, sempre que vamos utilizar a nova biblioteca, ao usar as sugestões de importação do VS Code (Ctrl + Espaço) as primeiras sugestões sempre são da biblioteca antiga. Existem casos que realmente é dificil identificar a novo biblioteca, já que o nome dos componentes são identicos.

Existe alguma maneira de desabilitar a sugestão de uma biblioteca especifica?